# how to align the text in the text box in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I don't know how to align the text in the text box. I need to change the font size, font type in the text box. Is anybody know that means send me the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its rather simple.

Follow these steps and you will be done with what you need.

1. In your storyboard, select your text box and then open up the Interface Builder.
2. In the Interface Builder,you will see properties for "Alignment","Text Size" and Color.
3. Make appropriate changes there and your done.

Hope this helps.